# Maximum document size exceeded

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This a pretty common problem in MongoDB but I couldn't find anything that could help. I am trying to aggregate two collections containing a common key but I get a "maximum document size exceeded" error.

The Meal collection is every meal consumed by a specific individual while HasConsumed is every food this individual has eaten during the meal.

Meal contains 171318 items while HasConsumed contains 541526 items.

Here's the query :

```
    db.getCollection('Meal').aggregate(
    {
       $lookup:
         {
           from: "HasConsumed",
           localField: "nomen_nojour_tyrep",
           foreignField: "nomen_nojour_tyrep",
           as: "conso"
         }},
        { $out : "hasConsumed" }
    )
```

Comment: It is not clear from your question whether you need all data from the joined collections. If not, you can try to reduce the document size by filtering with $match and $project operators.

Comment: I do need all the data. As a test, I did try to split the size of the collection by 3 but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use [allowDiskUse](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) option in your pipeline:

```
 db.getCollection('Meal').aggregate([
    {
       $lookup:
         {
           from: "HasConsumed",
           localField: "nomen_nojour_tyrep",
           foreignField: "nomen_nojour_tyrep",
           as: "conso"
         }},
        { $out : "hasConsumed" }


    ],{ allowDiskUse: true} )
```

Comment: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'allowDiskUse'

Comment: I get back to the same error I got at the beginning